# Download Azure web app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I just opened a free Azure trial account and went through the various forms to create a test web app. I would like to edit the source files locally with Visual Studio 2015 however. Is it possible to download the files generated during sign-up, and if so, how? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 37):

You can download your project file using KUDU site: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/

Select Debug console -> CMD
from there you can go inside site -> wwwroot and select download button to the left of any folder:

[image]

It will zip up all the files under that folder and start downloading.

Comment: For my C# MVC 5 Web App, this gives me the files for the JavaScript files, and the Views. This does not give me the files for the Models or ViewModels, the Controllers, the actual code. Is there anyway to download that information? Or is that all compressed in some manner during publishing?

Comment: yes, when you publish from visual studio or any CI tool the files gets published in compiled form. One option is you can use github deployment it maintains a folder repository which contains all models and views separately.

Comment: Kudu is available now from the Azure Portal in an App Service under Advanced Tools.

Comment: DebugConsole can be reached directly at:  `https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

Answer (score 4):

Web apps are accessible via ftp, so you can download/upload individual files.

[image: ftp access]

However: The idea is that you should be editing locally, then pushing your changes *to* your web app deployment, not pulling *from*. To facilitate this, not only do you have ftp, but you also have git/github,bitbucket, dropbox, etc. just look under your Publishing settings, for Deployment Source:

[image: deployment options]

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I decided to just delete the app I created while signing up and re-create it from within Visual Studio; worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

From azure console or kudo console , you can push using git to your azure devops repository or any repository

```
git init 
git remote add <url>
git add . 
git push origin master
```

Comment: i had issue in adding all files so i made some exception :git add --all -- :!.git :! cgi-bin :!dup-installer :! .htaccess :! .ftpquota